# cakephp how to find belongs to by id

Tags: cakephp, orm, find

Is there a way in cakephp using ORM to get the item that belongs to a specific child item. For example I was to get the related Post record for a specific Comment records.

This is my Comment model:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Post' => array(
        'className' => 'Post',
        'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

I was trying this but it's pull back every post, even those that don't have the comment I'm querying against:

```
$this->Post->contain('Comment');
$results = $this->Post->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'id' => 15
           )
        )
)));
```

Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have to specify the model in your conditions?

For example:

```
$this->Post->contain('Comment');
$results = $this->Post->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Comment.id' => 15
           )
        )
)));
```

Comment: it works without specifying the table name, the issue is it pulls back other posts as well that don't contain the comment, they just have a blank array for comment. however, i want it to ONLY pull back posts that contain the comment. i could fix the array using:            foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
                if (empty($value['Comment'])) {
                    unset($results[$key]);
                }
            } but would like to do it in the query for optimization sake

Comment: I can't think of a way to do that off the top of my head without grabbing too much and filtering it down. In fact, I think if you do find a way to specify those conditions, cake might still be querying for everything and then filtering it down. You might have to do a SQL query for this.

Answer (score 0):

my research led me to this post regarding the issue with contains:
http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/07/17/forcing-an-sql-join-in-cakephp/

so my final solution was as follows:

```
    $this->Post->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => array('Comment')));

    $results = $this->Post->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array(
            'Comment' => array(
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array('Comment.post_id = Post.id'))
        )));

    $results = $this->Post->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Comment.id' => 10
                )));
```

not pretty but gets the job done :)